# Short bash script to join arguments with dashoption, escaping quotes and $ dollar sign

Tags: bash

So I got this short awk invocation wrapped in a bash script. unfortunately the bash script is kinda unreadable. Do you have any pointers?

```
#!/bin/bash
action="printf \"$1 \" \$1 \" \""
awk {"$action"} $2
```

Invoking it like this `joinargs -s tmp` if the tmp file looks like:

```
a
bb
ccc
```

would create this output `-s a -s bb -s ccc` and it's useful when assembling commands

Comment: Can't you use just `echo` for printing to stdout?

Comment: `sed "s/^/$1 /" $2 | xargs` ?

Comment: @paladin how do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why we're using Bash here - we're not using any features that aren't available in plain `sh`.

You forgot to quote the expansion of `$2` - we don't want that subject to word-splitting.

---

Composing AWK commands like this is fragile - what if `$1` contains `;`, `}` or anything else with significance to the interpreter?

The usual remedy is to pass an AWK variable on the command line with `-v`:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -eu

prefix=$1
shift
awk -v p="$prefix" \
    '{printf "%s %s ", p, $1}' \
    "$@"
```

See that this makes the command more readable, too!